Solving libsvtav1enc1d1 conflict on Debian 12
The package doesn't let itself remove itself and doesn't let itself be properly installed what is the problem?
sudo apt install libsvtav1enc1d1 Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt: libavtp0 libbdplus0 libdirectfb-1.7-7 libkcolorpicker0 libkimageannotator-common libkimageannotator0 liblrdf0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmpeg2-4 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libneon27 libopenni2-0 libplacebo208 libpocketsphinx3 libsidplay1v5 libsphinxbase3 libvidstab1.1 pocketsphinx-en-us Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen. Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert: libsvtav1enc1d1 0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert. 92 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt. Es müssen noch 0 B von 2.169 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden. Nach dieser Operation werden 6.918 kB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt. (Lese Datenbank ... 636802 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.) Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../libsvtav1enc1d1_1.7.0+dfsg-2+b1_amd64.deb ... Entpacken von libsvtav1enc1d1:amd64 (1.7.0+dfsg-2+b1) ... dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/libsvtav1enc1d1_1.7.0+dfsg-2+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack): Versuch, »/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSvtAv1Enc.so.1« zu überschreiben, welches auch in Paket libsvtav1enc1:amd64 2:1.5.0-dmo1 ist Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von: /var/cache/apt/archives/libsvtav1enc1d1_1.7.0+dfsg-2+b1_amd64.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
used sudo rm -rf.
Something
